# BigQuery failed load job - was unable to access a GCS file

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We encountered an error in one of our scheduled load jobs for BigQuery yesterday. We've never seen this error before. In addition, re-running the job soon afterwards (without any changes) worked fine. Thus, cannot reproduce.

We're loading the files in from GCS. Here's the error that BigQuery/GCS came back with:

> Access Denied: Google Storage File [file name removed]: Access Denied

Just that one file out of ~50 source uri's was not accessible. The job id of failed job:

> job_TFuRwMrEWVAMD-PNuc29Yx_PXkk

The job id of the re-run job later in the day which worked fine again (no changes made):

> job_Pt9usLRO9elxIBlmuOwCGB-drxI

Anyone have an idea why this happened?

Comment: If helps yesterday we seen some unusual activity on our side too, maybe it was a deploy error or service error.

Comment: Looks like GCS was playing up. Not seen it since. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the job logs in the BigQuery import workers... from what I can tell when we tried to get the file size of one of Cloud Storage files we hit an ACCESS_DENIED error. Are you certain that the ACL did not change before the second job was run? It may have been a temporary glitch in Cloud Storage.

Comment: ACL did definitely not change. These jobs have been running for a few months without any problems. I agree that it looks like a glitch in GCS but thought I'd flag it anyway. I've now implemented some error handling in case it happens again.

Comment: Could you share how do you catch this kind of errors?

Comment: When polling the job for its status, you can check if it failed or not. The error result is wrapped up in the JSON response so you can handle it how ever you want to - we simply keep retrying the job.

Comment: Btw, did you see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468181/frequent-503-errors-raised-from-bigquery-streaming-api#

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread. That is actually another developer on our team who raised that issue. It's becoming a real problem for us now. We're getting 503's every day which means our daily jobs are failing.

Comment: Do you have job ids of any more of the failed jobs?