# BigQuery Backend Error when attempting to load a JSON file

Tags: google-bigquery

We are seeing intermittent (not all jobs fail) Backend errors when attempting to create a table from a JSON file in GS from the Browser UI.

There is only a red pop up with the "Backend Error" message, no other information and it goes away after a few seconds.

How can we troubleshoot or gather additional information about this error?

Comment: Check with Jordan, he has an answer on other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394173/bigquery-failed-load-job-was-unable-to-access-a-gcs-file?noredirect=1#comment34120916_22394173

Comment: Pentium10 thank you for the suggestion. @JordanTigani any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a job id? If you click on the "Job History"  button in the upper left of the Web UI it will show recently run jobs; the failed ones will be in red. If you click to expand it will show the job id and information about what happened.

Comment: @JordanTigani - Thank you for the suggestion. There is no job id because the job does not go into the job history. The browser's java console shows the server responds with a 500. It turns out it was a problem with the schema definition. One of the fields had a name but was missing the 'type'. This fixed the problem.